# vb3DShadow & vb3DHighlight in vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net, colors, draw

Am trying to create a 3d line control using lineshape control in vb2008, and i need these two color format vb3DShadow & vb3DHighlight, but can't seem to find it in .net. I originally used it in vb6.
i got the line shape control from visualbasicpowerpacks.

can someone help me with  these colors version in vb.net or help me draw the control in another way using the graphics class of vb.net 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the replacement

System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight

System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark

thanks for those who participated